# Problems with \section and \input

Tags: sectioning, errors, input

new member here. Have been doing really well with guidance and answers to other problems but got to a point where I really cannot find the answer to my problem. Two-pronged problem, really.
I am writing my thesis and using \input to join separate chapters. It's looking something like this at the moment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,]{book}     
\usepackage{warwickthesis,setspace,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm=bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, fullpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headsep 20pt
\rhead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true, plainpages=false} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0.5em}{\vspace{0.5ex}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}                  
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[numbers, super, comma, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\begin{thesisabstract}              
\input{abstract.tex}
\end{thesisabstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{intro.tex}

\chapter{Techniques and Methodology}
\input{experimental.tex}

\chapter{Cinnamates}
\input{cinnamates.tex}

\chapter{Anthranilates}
\input{anthranilates.tex}

\chapter[Structure-Function-Dynamics]{Structure-Function-Dynamics:\\From fundamental science\\to product}
\input{sfd.tex}

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}
\input{conclusion.tex}

\begin{appendix}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
    \input{app.tex}
\end{appendix}

    \end{document}
```

I'm sorry if it is not the most elegant code, I've been adding bits and bobs here and there seeing what works. I tried deleting what I thought was not relevant but didn't want to take much from the preamble in case there is something conflicting that I am not aware of!

I currently only have content in intro.tex (which works fine), antranilates.tex and sfd.tex. The latter two generate a 'File ended while scanning use of \section.' error (which has, however, since disappeared for anthranilates.tex but still there for sfd.tex. **How do I solve this problem?**

Also, while anthranilates.tex is working, **the section name does not appear after compile, and the first letter of the line is deleted**. I.e. my .tex file starts with:

```
\section{Overview}
Testing
```

And I simply get 'esting' straigth after the chapter title, with no '1.1 Overview' title. Note that, for the Introdction chapter, I used the exact same thing and it worked a treat. So not sure what is going wrong now.

I hope I've given you something you can work with. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Nat

---

working MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,]{book}     
%\usepackage{warwickthesis,setspace,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm=bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, fullpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headsep 20pt
\rhead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true, plainpages=false} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0.5em}{\vspace{0.5ex}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}                  
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[numbers, super, comma, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
%\begin{thesisabstract}              
%\input{abstract.tex}
%\end{thesisabstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
%\input{intro.tex}
iiii

\chapter{Techniques and Methodology}
%\input{experimental.tex}
eeee

\chapter{Cinnamates}
%\input{cinnamates.tex}
ccc

\chapter{Anthranilates}
%\input{anthranilates.tex}
\section{Overview}
Testing

\chapter[Structure-Function-Dynamics]{Structure-Function-Dynamics:\\From fundamental science\\to product}
%\input{sfd.tex}
sss

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}
%\input{conclusion.tex}
ccc

\begin{appendix}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
    %\input{app.tex}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\input` has essentially no affect on latex, it is just as if the contents of the file were copied in to the main document at that point.  the error `File ended while scanning use of \section.` means you have `\section{foo`  with a missing `}` somewhere, but hard to say where, given the information provided.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if \input only copies things into the document, and the file I am copying has \section{title} on it, then surely the title should be printed onto the main document? Or am I missing something?

Regarding the error, I will look more closely for a missing }. Thank you!

Comment: we could not run your example as it inputs your section files and uses a non standard `warwickthesis` class, however I added a version that can be run but the `Testing` and `Overview` section appear as expected. Can you edit that example adding enough bits of warwickthesis so that it breaks?

Comment: After you get _any_ error then any behaviour or pdf output is essentially accidental behaviour due to error recovery. TeX does not try to make sensible output after an error, just allow the document to be further processed for syntax checking.

Comment: Ok so I deleted all the text from the sfd.tex file and the error went away, so it must have been something in that text - I will go through it more carefully later to make sure. 

About the rest - I can share the .sty file if that would be easier? if not, should I simply go over the code and comment out parts until it works?

Comment: so you mean currently you get no error but the section level  headings are still messed up? If so you can probably just add the .sty here (unless it has a licence that forbids that) it would be good if you could get a version like the example I added to break (uncommenting the warwickthesis but with inlined sections rather than `\input` as that is easier for people to test)

Comment: Well, actually, simply using that code (your MWE) and uncommenting the warwickthesis all together (no changes) makes it work fine. So the error is not coming from there?

Comment: Ok well if you can make an example that makes an error, someone can debug it, sorry can't help any more given the information so far.

Comment: Your MWE works even after uncommenting warwickthesis style. My code does not, still has no section title and missing first letter. Is there a system to share the .sty file or should I edit my question and add the code?

Comment: you can add the sty here (subject to any licence conditions on that file, and the 30000 character limit on questions) but you need to also make an example that we can run and which fails, so without all your `\input`